# Why does Scala implicit resolution fail for overloaded method with type parameter?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, implicits

The first example successfully finds the implicit conversion to the method `foo(String)`, however as soon as I add a type parameter (see `fails`) the compiles doesn't resolve it anymore:

```
object works {
  class A {
    def foo(): String = ???
  }
  implicit class PimpedA(a: A) {
    def foo(i: String): String = ???
  }
  val a = new A()
  a.foo("test") //compiles
}

object fails { //same as `works`, but adds type parameter
  class A {
    def foo[T](): String = ???
  }
  implicit class PimpedA(a: A) {
    def foo[T](i: String): String = ???
  }
  val a = new A()
  PimpedA(a).foo("test") // compiles
  a.foo("test") // error: too many arguments for method foo: ()String
}
```

This behaviour is the same for Scala 2.11.7 and 2.12.0-M3.

The documentation on implicits doesn't seem to cover this and I didn't find this exact case on stackoverflow.

Note that my goal is to overload the method `foo` - if i rename it, the compiler finds it.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html

Comment: Why are you using the same name `foo` for the pimped one? Maybe it is obvious, but if you call it `bar` the error doesn't manifest

Comment: I know, but I want to overload `foo` - I've just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Both cases seem to fall under this case of [the specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicit-parameters-and-views.html#views):

> Views are applied in three situations:
>
> ...
>
> In a selection `e.m(args)` with `e` of type `T`, if the selector `m` denotes some member(s) of `T`, but none of these members is applicable to the arguments `args`. In this case a view `v` is searched which is applicable to `e` and whose result contains a method `m` which is applicable to `args`. The search proceeds as in the case of implicit parameters, where the implicit scope is the one of `T`. If such a view is found, the selection `e.m` is converted to `v(e).m(args)`.

So it should work. I was actually surprised to see it, because I've never run into the working case before and assumed that there is no implicit search if `T` has any members named `m`. I've taken a quick look at http://issues.scala-lang.org/, but couldn't find a relevant issue.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I've created an issue on the scala-lang jira: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9523