# Scala: Why foreach with a single argument function does not work with a zipped result

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala program:

```
object Test extends App {
  val zip = (List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 4, 6)).zipped

  val f: Tuple2[Int, Int] => Unit = x => println(x._1 + x._2)

  zip.foreach(f)
}
```

Why I get the following compiler error:

```
Error:(6, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : ((Int, Int)) => Unit
 required: (Int, Int) => ?
 zip.foreach(f)
```

when there is an implicit conversion from `Tuple2Zipped` to `Traversable` where `foreach[U](f: ((El1, El2)) => U): Unit` is defined.

### NOTE: I edited my question to clarify.

I know that the `foreach` defined in `Tuple2Zipped` has the following signature:

```
def foreach[U](f: (El1, El2) => U): Unit
```

and that my function `f` does not fit as the argument.

But in Tuple2Zipped.scala is defined the trait `ZippedTraversable2` and his companion object this way:

```
trait ZippedTraversable2[+El1, +El2] extends Any {
  def foreach[U](f: (El1, El2) => U): Unit
}
object ZippedTraversable2 {
  implicit def zippedTraversable2ToTraversable[El1, El2](zz: ZippedTraversable2[El1, El2]): Traversable[(El1, El2)] = {
    new scala.collection.AbstractTraversable[(El1, El2)] {
      def foreach[U](f: ((El1, El2)) => U): Unit = zz foreach Function.untupled(f)
    }
  }
}
```

so as my function **`f` does match the argument of the `foreach` defined in the `Traversable` returned by `zippedTraversable2ToTraversable`** and the companion object **defines an implicit conversion from `ZippedTraversable2` to this  `Traversable`** and **`Tuple2Zipped` is a `ZippedTraversable2`**, i think that this conversion has to be tried and my function be accepted.

The Intellij Idea editor accepts my construct without reporting any error but the compiler fails with the shown error.

Comment: You are calling `.foreach` on `Tuple2Zipped`, such method exists, why would compiler apply conversion? http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions (option #2).

Comment: But `foreach[U](f: ((El1, El2)) => U): Unit` is not a member of `Tuple2Zipped` but `Traversable` so the conversion is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Jasper-M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374461/jasper-m) I have known that a Scala bug has been reported on this issue: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9523. This bug was reported by [Michael Pollmeier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/452762/michael-pollmeier) that asked this question one and a half years ago: [Why does Scala implicit resolution fail for overloaded method with type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162618/why-does-scala-implicit-resolution-fail-for-overloaded-method-with-type-paramete)

[jamborta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560163/jamborta) posted a question with a more generic example on this same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402995/implicit-conversion-is-not-applied-if-generics-are-present).

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another, and slightly more esoteric, way to fix your code.

```
zip.foreach(Function.untupled(f))
```

`Function.untupled()` will take a `((Int, Int)) => Unit`, which is what you've got in `f`, and return a `(Int, Int) => Unit`, which is what you need to process the `zip` elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I edited my question to clarify it. The call to Function.untupled(f) is precisely what the foreach in ZippedTraversable2 does.

Answer (score 0):

Your function f is wrong ( it's also explicitly stated in the error )

`zip.foreach` expectes `Function2` that takes type `T1`, type `T2` and returns `R`, but you are passing a `Function1` that takes `Tuple2[Int,Int]` as type `T1`

Here's an explaination  regarding your compilation error :

`found   : ((Int, Int)) => Unit`   EQUALS  `Function1[Tuple2[Int,Int]] => Unit`

Whereas

`required: (Int, Int) => Unit` EQUALS `Function2[Int,Int,Unit]`

(Keep in mind that `()` is syntactic sugar for `Tuple*` , that's why your are seeing the double parenthesis)

Here's an example that compiles :

```
val zip = (List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 4, 6)).zipped
val f:Function2[Int,Int,Unit]  = (x,y) => println(x + y)
zip.foreach[Unit](f)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I edited my question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Your object is a `runtime.Tuple2Zipped`, if you look at the signature

```
def foreach[U](f: (El1, El2) => U): Unit
```

It takes a function `f: (El1, E1l2) => U`, but your function is `f: ((El1, El2)) => U`, hence the error.

I found it confusing too, as `Tuple2Zipped` almost looks like a `List[(A,B)]`, in fact the `toList` method would produce just that:

```
val zip = (List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 4, 6)).zipped.toList
val f: Tuple2[Int, Int] => Unit = x => println(x._1 + x._2)
zip.foreach(f)
```

**Edit**

I think you are looking for an implicit conversion from `((A, B)) => U` to `(A, B) => U` which is not what `zippedTraversable2ToTraversable` does. You can define something like this that would work:

```
implicit def tupconv[A,B] (f: (((A,B)) => Unit)): (A, B) => Unit = Function.untupled(f)
```

**Edit V2**

For the code above you'd need an implicit variable in scope that would map from `((A,B)) => Unit` to `(A, B) => Unit` as that's where the mismatch is. Whereas the one you quoted does `ZippedTraversable2[El1, El2]` to `Traversable[(El1, El2)]`. If you'd like to make use of that implicit conversion, you could do this:

```
val zip = (List(1, 3, 5), List(2, 4, 6)).zipped
val f: Tuple2[Int, Int] => Unit = x => println(x._1 + x._2)
def thisUsesTheImplicitYouWant(t: Traversable[(Int,Int)]) = t.foreach(f)
thisUsesTheImplicitYouWant(zip)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I edited my question to clarify it.

Comment: No, I am not looking for an implicit conversion from `((A, B)) => U to (A, B) => U`, what I am saying is that **there is** an implicit conversion from `ZippedTraversable2` to `Traversable` that has to be used when invoking a method, `foreach[U](f: ((El1, El2)) => U): Unit`, **that exists** in `Traversable` but not in `ZippedTraversable2`

Comment: @jmbeleta I see what you mean. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: `toTraversable` is already in the standard library. So this works, `zip.toTraversable.foreach(f)`, but it doesn't answer the question of why the implicit doesn't kick in.

Comment: @jwvh yes, that's the point. Perhaps is a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @jwvh Am I missing something? `zippedTraversable2ToTraversable` would only kick in if the compiler thinks `ZippedTraversable` needs to be converted to `Traversable`.

Comment: @jamborta the implicit conversion is **already** in the scala library. It is in the companion object of a trait `ZippedTraversable2` that mixins `Tuple2Zipped` so it is in scope. This is why I think this should work with no further implicit conversions. In my example use for example `zip.size` and this compile with no problem and `size` is **not defined** in `Tuple2Zipped`.

Comment: @jamborta and `Tuple2Zipped ` need to be converted to `ZippedTraversable2 ` in my case because `foreach[U](f: ((El1, El2)) => U): Unit` is not defined in `Tuple2Zipped` but in `Traversable`.

Comment: @jmbeleta Interesting. Do you mind if I post a new question on this with a simplified example? I'm kind of curious what's going on.

Comment: @jamborta fantastic, go on!

Comment: @jamborta I said incorrectly that `foreach[U](f: ((El1, El2)) => U): Unit` is defined in `Traversable`.This is not true, is defined in the `Traversable` returned by the implicit conversion contained in `ZippedTraversable2`.