# Implicit conversion is not applied if a method has type parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

The question is based on the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381618/scala-why-foreach-with-a-single-argument-function-does-not-work-with-a-zipped-r/). This is the setup:

```
implicit def CToC2(obj: C1): C2 = {
  new C2()
}

class C1() {
  def f[U](f: (Int, Int) => U): U = f(1, 1)
}

class C2() {
  def f[U](f: ((Int, Int)) => U): U = f(2, 2)
}
```

I'd expect that trying to call the function with a signature that exists in `C2`, scala would use the implicit conversion to satisfy the call:

```
val c1 = new C1()
val ff: ((Int, Int)) => Unit = t => println(t._1 + t._2)
```

But this fails:

```
scala> c1.f(ff)
Error:(16, 7) type mismatch;
 found   : ((Int, Int)) => Unit
 required: (Int, Int) => ?
```

Interestingly if I drop the type parameter from `C1`, it works fine:

```
class C1() {
  def f(f: (Int, Int) => Unit): Unit = f(1, 1)
}
```

Comment: More interesting is that  you need to drop parameter even if it's not used, e.g. `def f[U](f: (Int, Int) => Unit): Unit = f(1, 1)` doesn't compile too.

Comment: You don't even have to make it that complicated. You get the same thing with `def f[U](f: Int): Unit = ???` and `def f(f: String): Unit = ???`

Comment: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9523

Comment: there is now a PR with a fix for Scala 2.13